# Почему не работают ip адреса Cloudflare?

Tags: proxy, vpn, cloudflare, cdn

Здравствуйте я хочу сделать vpn через cdn. И я сразу подумал о Клоудфейре,

1. Короче я поднял dropbear server с stunnel (как я раньше делал с mcs cdn).
2. Потом я зарегал на клоуде свой домен с прокси на мой сервак (как я понял он автоматическо подключает cdn) . Теперь при пинге этого домейна он мне выдает заблокированные ip адреса нашей страны.
3. Смысл я хочу сделать так чтобы он шел через другой ip adres клоудфейра которые в нашей стране работают, типа перепроксировать все именно через них. Можно ли придумать что-то схожее чтобы решить проблему? (*айпи сервера тоже заблокирован, здесь нету ничего мы такое делали с mcs просто что то случилось с их адреса то что они теперь не работают. )

Спасибо за ваше время!

Comment: Dropbear вы имеете в виду ssh? Cloudflare его не поддерживает

Comment: Здравствуйте, в этом видео он поднимает то что я вам говорю, но здесь он как я сказал перепроксирует через другой ip(domain) cloudflare. А этот домейн не работает у нас и как искать такие он не расказывает. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ie9c0A6a0U